# How to show directions on an iOS Google map within a Titanium Alloy application

Tags: ios, google-maps, titanium-alloy

Are there any add on modules for Titanium Alloy that let you show directions on a Google map in an iOS application? I.e. I want to show a marked route showing how a car, for example, could get from A to B. I know how to add lines to the map but don't know how to work out the route or better still get this done automatically.

I can obviously do this by creating a webview but would rather not do it that way if possible.

Answer (score 1):

iOS Map Kit can show annotations then can containing places such as directions.

Alloy Controller: **index.js**

```
var MapModule = require('ti.map');
var opera = MapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude: -33.8569,
    longitude: 151.2153,
    centerOffset: {x: 80, y: 25},
    image: 'SydneyOperaHouse.jpg',
    title: 'Sydney Opera House',
    subtitle: 'Sydney, New South Wales, Australia',
 // For eventing, use the Map View's click event
 // and monitor the clicksource property for 'rightButton'.    
    rightButton: Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.CONTACT_ADD
});

var bridge = MapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude: -33.852222,
    longitude: 151.210556,
    pincolor: MapModule.ANNOTATION_PURPLE,   
    title: 'Sydney Harbour Bridge',
    subtitle: 'Port Jackson',
 // For eventing, use the Map View's click event
 // and monitor the clicksource property for 'leftButton'.
    leftButton: Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.INFO_DARK
});

var mapview = MapModule.createView({
    mapType: MapModule.NORMAL_TYPE,
    region: {latitude: -33.87365, longitude: 151.20689, latitudeDelta: 0.1,     longitudeDelta: 0.1 },
    annotations: [bridge,opera]
});
$.index.add(mapview);
$.index.open();
```

[image]

Do not fortget to include this module in your *Tiapp.xml* i.e.

```
<modules>
    <!-- Add this line to your modules section -->
    <module platform="iphone">ti.map</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: Thank Eduardo. I have updated my question to make it clearer that I need to plot a route along roads from A to B.

Comment: Add a [route](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.Route-property-points) setting points up. That should plot the road

Comment: If necessary a CSV file type can store the points to enable your MapView with routing. Demo: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/map_view2.js#L28

Comment: Is there a function to automatically plot a route between two lat/lng coordinate pairs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to draw on Google Map
// draw path on map

-(void)getDrivingDirection

{

[mapGoogleView clear];

```
cameraGoogleMap = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[locationSourceLat floatValue] longitude:[locationSourceLong floatValue] zoom:15];
[mapGoogleView setCamera:cameraGoogleMap];

CLLocationCoordinate2D positionSource = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([locationDestLat floatValue], [locationDestLong floatValue]);
GMSMarker *markerSource = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:positionSource];
markerSource.map = mapGoogleView;

NSString *strDirection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@,%@&destination=%@,%@&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCdq4_-Isxdkvn1LBx8aw7AvdQiWLEqqQ8",locationSourceLat,locationSourceLong,locationDestLat,locationDestLong];
NSLog(@"GOOGLE DRAW URL %@",strDirection);
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[strDirection stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray* latestRoutes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];
NSString *points=[[[latestRoutes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"];

@try
{
    NSArray *temp= [self decodePolyLine:[points mutableCopy]];
    GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];

    for(int idx = 0; idx < [temp count]; idx++)
    {
        CLLocation *location=[temp objectAtIndex:idx];
        [path addCoordinate:location.coordinate];
    }
    // create the polyline based on the array of points.

    GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    rectangle.strokeWidth = 5.0;
    rectangle.map = mapGoogleView;
}
@catch (NSException * e)
{
    // TODO show error
    NSLog(@"");
}
NSLog(@"%f",mapGoogleView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude);
```

}

// decode polylines to draw path

-(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine: (NSMutableString *)encoded
{
    [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];
    NSInteger len = [encoded length];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
    NSInteger lat=0;
    NSInteger lng=0;
    while (index < len)
    {
        NSInteger b;
        NSInteger shift = 0;
        NSInteger result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        NSNumber *latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5] ;
        NSNumber *longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5] ;
        //        printf("[%f,", [latitude doubleValue]);
        //        printf("%f]", [longitude doubleValue]);
        CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]] ;
        [array addObject:loc];
    }

```
return array;
```

}